# Local Variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am getting an UnboundLocalError. I don't know why, I was following a tutorial on YouTube on AI Chatbots (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lwddP0KUEg), and the code was the same as his. His worked, mine didn't.
Code:

```
def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
    tag = intents_list[0]['intent']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    return result


print("GO!")

while True:
    message = input("")
    ints = predict_classes(message)
    res = get_response(ints, intents)
    print(res)
```

Comment: What if `list_of_intents` is empty or no tag matches…? How is `result` defined then?

Answer (score 1):

If `list_of_intents` is empty, or if there is no element in the list that satisfies the `if` condition - `result` will not be defined. Therefore, when you try to `return result` you get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

To solve this, you should define `result` before the `for` loop with a default value.

In addition, it sounds like the `get_response` function doesn't get the values you expect (i.e `intents_list`'s and\or `intents_json`'s content is different than what you are expecting). You can `print` their content to debug this.

In addition, it is better not to have the type of the object as part of its name. I would change `list_of_intents` to `intents` or maybe  `intents_contents`.